# Tame ramification of (mild) curve singularities.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, ramification, singularity-theory

Suppose that $C$ and $D$ are curves of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ (we make some of these hypotheses for simplicity).  We view these as pointed curves with singularities $c \in C$ and $d \in D$.  I'm happy to assume that these singularities look analytically locally like $n$-coordinate-lines through the origin in $\mathbb{A}^n$; in other words $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(\dots, x_i x_j, \dots)$.

If you'd like to start with simple (planar) nodes (ie, $k[x,y]/(xy)$), that's ok too.

Further suppose that there is a finite map $C \to D$ taking $c$ to $d$.

**Question**:  Is there an accepted notion of what it means for such a map to have tame ramification at $d$?

Particularly, has it been studied before, and if so, where can I read about it?

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea if there's an accepted notion, but in case you're also interested in possible definitions, here's one from logarithmic algebraic geometry. When $C$ and $D$ are smooth curves, being tame at $c$ is equivalent to being log-etale, where the log structures on $C$ and $D$ are the ones inherited from the trivial log structures on $C-\{c\}$ and $D-\{d\}$. (At least, that's how I remember it. It's been a while.) So it seems to me that the same definition would still be a reasonable candidate without any smoothness assumptions, though of course everything depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea and one I hadn't thought of.  In the log smooth setting, we're only going to be looking at nodes (2 points glued), right?  It's been awhile since I thought about log geometry.   

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference that may be relevant (you may know it already): Auslander-Rim has a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-7/issue-4/Ramification-index-and-multiplicity/10.1215/ijm/1255645095.full) called "Ramification index and multiplicity" . Even though they mostly discussed normal rings, their definition of tame ramification used only Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity, so it can be adapted to non-normal situations.

Comment: Long, I meant to mention this to you a while ago, but forgot.  The *ramification index* they are discussing seems to be a different one than the modern one (at least in the wildly ramified setting).  

Comment: @Karl: that's too bad, sorry it didn't help. 